# How to install a series of Julia packages from a file

Tags: julia

In Python, if I install `mambaforge` or `conda` then I can make a file with extension `.yml` and then inside it list the name of packages I want to install alongside their specific versions. How can I do a similar way of installing packages in Julia?
I understand that if I have already installed Julia packages by `add`command in package manager, then I have a file named `Project.toml` which I can use to install the same packages later. However, this still does not look as good as Python's way of installing packages.

Upon further investigation I realized that to install Julia packages from an empty `Prokect.toml`file, I should add `[deps]`in the file followed by the name of packages I want and then give each package a `uuid`which can be found [here](https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General/blob/master/Registry.toml). For example:

```
[deps]
Images = "916415d5-f1e6-5110-898d-aaa5f9f070e0"
```

After all , this is still tedious as it needs to find all those `uuid`s.
How can I install packages in Julia the same way I described for Python?

Comment: Well, in Project.toml you can have a whole range of versions your package works with, and bunus if you use `add` you also have a file with all the dipendences and the dependences of the dependences... If you want use a simple text file with just the package names just make a small script that readlines and call `Pkgs.adds`

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason that you want to write package names to a `.yml` file and then read the packages from there? After all, you can `generate` the Project file and `add` multiple dependencies automatically:

```
(@v1.8) pkg> generate MyProject # or whatever name you like

(@v1.8) pkg> activate MyProject

(MyProject) pkg> add Countries Crayons CSV # some example packages
```

(In recent versions of Julia, an installation prompt will appear if a package isn't already installed).

Speaking from experience, learning to use environments in Julia can be challenging to a new user, but rewarding! [The documentation for Pkg.jl](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/) are helpful here.

If you are just assembling an environment for your own code, there is probably no need for you to manually edit `Project.toml`. On the other hand, if you are maintaining a package, you might wish to edit the file directly (e.g., for [specifying compatability](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/compatibility/)).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
using TOML
using HTTP
using DataStructures

## Get the Registry.toml file if it already doesn't exist in the current directory
function raed_reg()
    if !isfile("Registry.toml")
        HTTP.download(
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JuliaRegistries/General/master/Registry.toml",
            "Registry.toml"
        )

    end

    reg = TOML.parsefile("Registry.toml")["packages"]

    return reg
end

## Find the UUID of a specific package from the Registry.toml file
function get_uuid(pkg_name)
    reg = raed_reg()
    for (uuid, pkg) in reg
        if pkg["name"] == pkg_name
            return uuid
        end
    end
end


## Create a dictionary for the gotten UUIDs, by setting the name = UUID and convert it to a project.toml file
function create_project_toml(Pkgs::Vector{String})
    reg = raed_reg()
    pkgs_names_uuid = OrderedDict{AbstractString, AbstractString}()
    pkgs_names_uuid["[deps]"] = ""
    for pkg in Pkgs
        _uuid = get_uuid(pkg)
        pkgs_names_uuid[pkg] = _uuid
    end

    open("project.toml", "w") do io
        TOML.print(io, pkgs_names_uuid)
    end
end

## Test on the packages "ClusterAnalysis" and "EvoTrees"
create_project_toml(["ClusterAnalysis", "EvoTrees"])
```